# Is there a way to validate a .env file?

Tags: ini

I'm getting errors when trying to parse a .env file I have, but I have no way of figuring out where it's erring out. Is there an easy way to lint/validate the file, online or otherwise?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can try https://github.com/dotenv-linter/dotenv-linter.
It's a lightning-fast linter for .env files. Written in Rust.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the syntax you are using. Looking at the [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) and [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#rules) documentation, different tools seem to have a different scope on what they are able to parse.

I use a simple grep to validate if I have a `<key>=<value>` pattern, where key and value are non-empty. You can adapt the patterns to match your context, ensuring upper case keys for example.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for envfile in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.env.*'); do 
    for line in $(cat ${envfile}); do
        # exclude comments
        if [[ "${line:0:1}" == "#" ]]; then
            continue
        fi

        match_line=$(echo ${line} | grep -E "^[A-Za-z0-9_].+=.+$")

        if [[ ${match_line} == "" ]]; then
            echo "Error in file: ${envfile}: line: ${line}"
        fi
    done
done
```

Alternatively, look at your language loadenv library to see if you can catch specific parsing exceptions, if available, to narrow down the specific line that causes the error.

Comment: I found this useful but this does not work with string value that has space. You should change this line `for line in $(cat ${envfile}); do`  to `while IFS= read -r line;  ... ` to not trim the space